# Apache client request config builder error

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I write project using `Java` with `Spring` and `Maven dependencines`.
I have problem with `apache` when loading `xml` file and I try to find problem but I have no idea why it do not want load it.

Error info:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig$Builder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:82)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig.business.connector.IGInstrumentConnector.connect(IGInstrumentConnector.java:85)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig.IGStockProvider.connect(IGStockProvider.java:77)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig.IGStockProvider.connect(IGStockProvider.java:34)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.providers.business.manager.InstrumentConnectionManager.connect(InstrumentConnectionManager.java:65)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.business.managers.InstrumentController.initializeInstrument(InstrumentController.java:150)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.business.managers.InstrumentController.instrumentSelectedByConfig(InstrumentController.java:117)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.business.managers.ConnectionWindowManager$1.instrumentSelectedByConfig(ConnectionWindowManager.java:75)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.view.panel.ChoseInstrumentPanel$1.actionPerformed(ChoseInstrumentPanel.java:59)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1673)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1625)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.business.managers.ConnectionWindowManager.showInstrumentSelectionPopUp(ConnectionWindowManager.java:96)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.business.managers.InstrumentController.showChangeInstrumentWindow(InstrumentController.java:104)
    at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.view.components.InstrumentInitializeItem$1.run(InstrumentInitializeItem.java:88)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatch
```

Code which causes this error:

```
public void connect(IGConnection connection, IConnectorResultDelegate resultDelegate) {
    if (!isConnecting()) {

        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/public-api-client-spring-context.xml");
        connection.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        startConnecting(resultDelegate);
}
```

Maybe You need more code to help me ? 
I think that with dependencines are ok but I am not sure. My `pom.xml` fragment file looks like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The `public-api-client-spring-context.xml` file is in project `resources` folder

Content of `public-api-client-spring-context.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.iggroup.api"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig"/>

    <bean name="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>

    <bean name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="readTimeout" value="10000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.client.HttpClient" factory-bean="requestFactory"
            factory-method="getHttpClient"/>

    <bean name="apiservice" class="com.goodsoft.stockbox.ig.business.service.ApiService"/>
</beans>
```

**Any idea ?**

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? Is it `startConnecting(resultDelegate)` ?

Comment: `applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/public-api-client-spring-context.xml");` I read something about `NoClassDefFoundError` and it is throwing when dont have access to classpath while running (at compiling is ok)

Comment: can you provide the content of `/public-api-client-spring-context.xml` in your question, please?

Comment: Yea sure, I added now it :)

Comment: did you mention the dependency to `httpclient` within `dependencies` or within `dependencyManagement` ? The first would be correct

Comment: @Ulrich Yes, I created dependecines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I have a lot of modules in my project and other module overwrite `org.apache.httpclient` version and it caused conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This line in the spring context config file:

```
    <bean name="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.client.HttpClient" factory-bean="requestFactory"
        factory-method="getHttpClient"/>
```

Tries to load the apache HTTP client but obviously it is not available in the class path at run time. Did you forget to mention it as dependency in the maven pom.xml? Or do you not build the installation package by maven?

Comment: I wrote the fragment of content my `pom.xml` file and there is dependency to apache

Comment: I forgot build my maven package ;) Thanks!

Comment: Refresh. That was not solve my problem. I Think that worked but return other error and this is next error. Any idea ?

Comment: OK Thanks Henry :)